# Возможны варианты?

Tags: орфография

В последние годы всё чаще вижу в Сети слова с приставкой БЕЗ- в "неоглушенном" варианте — то есть через "**з**" перед глухими согласными.

«Бе**з**причинный», «бе**з**чувственный» и т.п..
Причём, такое можно встретить в текстах, написанных в целом весьма грамотно!

Что это — авторские вольности, возрождение дореволюционных форм слова или допуски современной  орфографии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написание З/С в приставках постоянно менялось. Раньше писали просто по произношению, но потом письменность  отошла от  фонетической, ведущим принципом становится морфологический, однако   сохранялись и фонетические написания.

По последним дореволюционным правилам через З писалась только приставка БЕЗ, ЧЕРЕЗ, в остальных наблюдалось чередование З/С. В 1918 году все приставки на З/С стали соответствовать произношению, правило упростилось.

В настоящее время никакой альтернативной орфографии нет, отражение чередования З/С является обязательным.

И еще хочется отметить следующее: если корень начинается на З/С, то происходит удвоение согласных СС и ЗЗ.  Мне кажется, то визуальный образ слов, где пишутся СС и ЗЗ более гармоничен по сравнению со словами, где встречаются ЗС, поэтому лучше бы оставить это правило без изменений, хотя оно и противоречит морфематическому письму.

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ, Софья!
Но тема вопроса осталась не вполне раскрыта...

Меня смущает не "чередование З и С" как таковое, а вольная отмена правила "оглушения / озвончения" перед соответствующими согласными в корне слова.

Это новая допустимая норма или люди просто путаются?

Comment: >> *если корень начинается на З/С , ‹...› **визуальный образ слов, где пишутся СС и ЗЗ более гармоничен** по сравнению со словами, где встречаются ЗС, поэтому лучше бы оставить это правило без изменений*

Да, у меня похожее ощущение. :)

Comment: Правила современной орфографии  считают  обязательным отражение чередования  З/С в приставках на письме, другие нормы не допускаются. А вот слова "беспричинный и бесчувственный" пишут так поклонники старой орфографии. Вот, например, такое объявление: "Группа любителей старой орѳографіи. Описание: Здѣсь собираются люди, которые считаютъ, что нужно вернуться къ старой орѳографіи, которымъ просто нравится писать дореволюціонными правилами".